# stuck with php forms

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I'm developing a php website;
I'm not using a pure object-oriented code, as I use classes only for my queries and functions, but am trying to use a MVC approach to have some clean view code for the html.
Everything goes ok as I'm separating the "business logic" and the views, the logic is all on my "controller" folder, than it passes all the variables to a view which displays.

I am stuck with forms.

I am passing the variable the form uses with the above approach, but, what about the form action? I should pass the $_POST data in a controller file.

if a "action" $_GET is retrieved, my admin view appears:

```
switch ($action) { 
    default:
        break;
    case "npr":
        require "controller/admincontents/inner/newproject.php";
        break;
    case "mpr":
        require "controller/admincontents/inner/modifyproject.php";
        break;
    case "dpr":
    require "controller/admincontents/inner/deleteproject.php";
    break;
}
```

then I go to my newproject.php which calls my form.

```
<?php 
require "views/adminviews/forms/insnuovoprogetto.php";
?>
```

the form have an action but where the action have to point? I want to perform a confirmation view, and a success view, but I can't put them in the same page.

if I don't use this approach, I can use the isset($_POST) function in order to turn the form, confirmations and success on and off.

Please can you redirect me to the approach to use in MVC for forms?

Comment: "the logic is all on my "controller" " That doesn't sound like MVC

Answer (score -1):

As per MVC structure,

1. Controller is decided by Url parameters ($_GET)
2. Same as, view file also need to be render depending on controller. You can create function like setLayout OR setView to render your view file
3. You have to mention your form action manually depending on controller

Answer (score -1):

It will be better to use any MVC framework rather than creating your own code. You can use php framework like codeigniter,cakePHP and Zend Framework. First of all try to understand how these framework operate and then start developing your own framework. Personally i feel Codeigniter is the best platform for a beginner to learn MVC apporach.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no time to do it. I have to finish the site in a pair of weeks. I came back to the "one file" and action='' approach, with the if else issets.